# Python plt plotting while in for loop - not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a simple self defined `sinc` function defined as follows (adapted from an old paper of Oliphant about Python for Scientific Computing):

```
from math import sin, pi
import NumPy as np 
def sinc(x):
    '''Compute the sinc function: sin(pi*x)/pi*x'''
    try:
        return sin(x)/x
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 1.0
    output = [sinc(x) for x in input]
```

To plot it (point by point, re-drawn/updated after each newly computed sinc value) i tried the following code:

```
pl = np.zeros(1001)
for x in range(1,1001,1): 
    pl[x]=sinc(x) 
    plt.plot(pl[x],c='blue')
    plt.pause(0.05)
plt.show()
```

where `plt` is the usual `matplotlib.pyplot`, `pl` is a `NumPy`. I can see the `matplotlib` frame with the axes and the axis limits increasing but the plot is simply not plotted/drawn/printed/shown(as in next picture)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMoy0.png)

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your issue is, whether it's using plt.plot rather than fig.plot, or plotting since on the range(0, 1000) as opposed to a smaller one e.g. (0, 2*pi). It may also be that you're initialising `pl` badly. Maybe you need to set `plt.ion()`. I managed to get this to work though

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.zeros(1000)

for index, xi in enumerate(x):
     y[index] = np.sinc(xi)
     ax.plot(x, y, color='b')
     plt.pause(0.01)
```

Result (after waiting a while)

[image]

Comment: nice one! this is exactly what i wanted to show during the presentation! Thanks!!!

Comment: Suprised than pause works but `time.sleep` doesn't. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Now you are creating a plot with a single point in each iteration. To see the point add add a marker to the plot (https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers).

```
plt.plot(pl[x],c='blue', marker='o')
```

If your intention is to create a plot as a curve of all points then you can create the plot after the loop with the list *pl* as first argument:

```
for x in range(1,1001,1): 
    pl[x]=sinc(x) 
plt.plot(pl[x],c='blue')    
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks! i want to plot the sinc function while it is computed (plot it point by point: as in it is re-drawn after each newly computed sinc value) to show it during a presentation.